# Telegram бот как изменить название кнопки при нажатии

Tags: javascript, бот, telegraf

использую telegraf фреймворк

у меня есть кнопка, когда я пишу в чат ss

```
bot.hears('ss', async (ctx) => {
    ctx.telegram.sendMessage(ctx.chat.id, 'Кликай',
    {
        reply_markup: {
            inline_keyboard: [[{text:"Key", callback_data: "nnn"}]]}
    }) 
})
```

вот action при нажатии на кнопку

```
bot.action('nnn',ctx=>{
    ctx.reply('кнопка нажата')
})
```

как я могу дописать кнопку, чтобы при клике на нее, кнопка меняла свое название, я понимаю что я должен саму кнопку удалять и создавать новую по идее, буду рад помощи

Answer (score 0):

```
bot.hears('ss', async (ctx) => {
    ctx.telegram.sendMessage(ctx.chat.id, 'Кликай',
    {
        reply_markup: {
            inline_keyboard: [[{text:"Key", callback_data: "nnn"}]]}
    }) 
})

bot.action('nnn',ctx=>{
        await ctx.editMessageReplyMarkup({
            inline_keyboard: [
              [{ text: '', callback_data: '' }],
            ],
          });
    ctx.reply('кнопка нажата')
})
```